# WordPress: The requested URL /myPost/ was not found on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I installed wordpress and configured and I wrote a post and publish the post but I get this error:

"The requested URL /myPost/ was not found on this server."

I modify my httpd.conf file and I add:

```
   <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
```

and I also add .htaccess in my web root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and restarted apache. But now I'm getting the following error:

Oops! That page can’t be found.

Any of you knows what is wrong or how can I fix this to able to see my post in wordpress?

I'll really appreciate you help.

Comment: when you edit the post, there is a link to preview, does that work?

Comment: Please look at the official [WordPress .htaccess doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess). The sample there looks quite different than what you use.

Comment: @LuckyChingi I used to be able to see the preview of the post but I published and now I can't see a preview.

Comment: @BendeLaporte tried all the posible conventions of wordpress .httaccess doc page but I still get the same error Oops! That page can’t be found.

Comment: @user2924482 To me it doesn't seem like an error in your .htaccess, because this error is generated by the index.php. So this is some kind of error in the WordPress routing. Can't help you there, sorry.

Comment: @user2924482 delete the htaccess file and try again

Comment: @LuckyChingi if I remove the htaccess I get page not found for the publish post but I can see the preview of a new post

Comment: great!, so now you need to go and change the permalink settings in WP admin. your .htaccess will be auto written

Comment: @LuckyChingi. This works. Thank you for your help

Comment: @user2924482 adding this as an answer for future references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused due to the permalinks now set correctly.

Perform the steps
1) delete the .htaccess file - WP will create it automatically
2) Change the permalink settings

WP site pages and posts works fine